# Terminal getting opened along with GUI Application

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal, gui, file-association

I have GUI application created using GTK in linux. Now if I launch the application by clicking on the icon or by using `xdg-open file.myextension`, an empty terminal gets opened along with the application GUI. This terminal and application gui are dependent because if I close the terminal the application gets closed and vice versa. Any reason why is this happening and how can I prevent the terminal from opening?

Comment: A specific, reproducible example will attract more useful answers than the current hypothetical.

Comment: Does the `.desktop` file have `Terminal=true`?

Comment: yes, had Terminal=True in the .desktop file, removing it resolved the issue. Thanks!